# Issue with "a" div in css

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of a problem, for the header of my website i used a styled div, called a so my http://puu.sh/d9Ax5/2817017ea2.png
but when i try to post a link i can't see it since it is already styled for the header.
Here is my code:

**HTML HEADER LIST**

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

**CSS**

```
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="/content_packs.html">Content Packs</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: instead of `a {` use `.nav a {` and it will limit style to the `a` tags inside of parent with `nav` class. Also take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving style directly to a, use .nav a.

```
.nav a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

This will help you to give the styles only to the 'a' inside the **nav** class and not any other 'a' in your code.

Comment: is there a way i can do it for other a tags?

Comment: use the respective class name or id (eg: .classname a{your style here;} or #id a{your style here;}) in front of the a tags if you want to apply separate styles to each of them.

Comment: im a bit confused, would it be like .logo a { ?

Comment: if your code is like this: `<div class="logo"><a href="">hai</a></div>` then your css will be `.logo a { }` OR if your code is : `<div id="logo"><a href="">hai</a></div>` then your css will be `#logo a { }`

Comment: please have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_syntax_id) & [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_syntax_class) for more info.